# Constant Timeouts with Spectrum on Certain Programs

Tags: home-networking, isp

I use Spectrum as my ISP and in Filezilla, WinSCP, Putty, MobaXTerm I timeout after about 3-4 minutes and have to reconnect. I have discussed it with my ISP and they swear it is something to do with my computer (or program) but I do not timeout while on other internet lines, Only my main home internet. I have a Motorola router, 300mbps Connection (Usually 230-320) and Spectrum 300 plan.

Comment: Is the connection idle when it times out?

Comment: Yes, But for no more than 5 minutes.

Comment: That doesn’t matter. You need to enable keepalives in your clients to keep the connection active. Stateful firewalls only keep a connection open for so long. This is not just an issue with Spectrum, this is anywhere, except the time may vary.

Comment: Yes, But I have friends with Spectrum as well and I never time out with my computer at their house.

Comment: i have added a Keepalive to WinSCP to see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by doing the following:

In WinSCP:

```
Site>Edit>Advanced>Enable Keepalives (I did every 30 seconds)
```

In MobaXTerm:

```
Settings>Configuration>SSH>Check "Keepalives" box
```

In FileZilla:

```
Edit>Settings>Connection>FTP>Enable FTP Keepalives
```

Thanks to Appleoddity for pointing me in the right direction.